# How to avoid "https://na32.visual.force.com/apex/vfpage" being added to output site link

Tags: visualforce, url, force.com-sites, outputlink

I'm trying to avoid **https://na32.visual.force.com/apex/vfpage** that is being added to the website that is already stored in field  **carrier_website__c**. **carrier_website__c** has values like the following:

1. https://www.google.com
2. http://google.com
3. www.google.com

This is how I tried:

```
    <apex:outputLink value="/{!q.Shipment_Number__r.carrier_website__c}" target="">
           <apex:outputText value="{!q.Shipment_Number__r.carrier_website__c}"/>
    </apex:outputLink>
```

I have tried with double quotes, double forward slash. I have also tried to use javascript **window.location**, but I face the same problem as discussed above. Any suggestions? 
Thanks.

**EDIT**: But if I remove the "/" in outputLink value, then the salesforce instance gets added like this.... abc.my.salesforce.com/www.carrierwebsite.com –

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is the / in the output link. That appends the URL to what you are entering. change to

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!q.Shipment_Number__r.carrier_website__c}" target="">
           <apex:outputText value="{!q.Shipment_Number__r.carrier_website__c}"/>
    </apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: The reason why / is an issue is that a leading / automatically causes the browser to assume the scheme and authority of the current page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if I remove the "/" then the salesforce instance gets added like this.... https://abc.my.salesforce.com/www.carrierwebsite.com

Comment: @MnZ - Does your URL stored in the field start with http(s)://something. If not try with a field that does (i.e. add http:// to the carrierwebsite)

Comment: Hi Eric, the URL custom field has the following format https://, http: and www.

Comment: @MnZ - and do the URL's with the HTTP:// work correctly?

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: If I remove '/' then the field containing www.google.com doesn't work. Only data starting with 'http' and 'https' works

Comment: @MnZ - That is the behavior of salesforce. You will need to check and see if the field starts with HTTP:// and if not add it in the formula. Otherwise salesforce will treat it as a relative URL