# Need help with Outputlink format

Tags: urlhacking, url, outputlink, conditional

This is in continuation of [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/58638/how-to-avoid-https-na32-visual-force-com-apex-vfpage-being-added-to-output-s) question I asked earlier.  I have a field **carrier_website__c** which contains URL starting from ***https***, **http** and **www**. But Salesforce appends its own URL in front if the URL starts with **www**. So I'm trying to write a conditional statement in visualforce. Following is the way I tried

```
<apex:outputLink value="{! IF (!CONTAINS('http', ''), 'http://{!q.Shipment_Number__r.carrier_website__c}', '{!q.Shipment_Number__r.carrier_website__c}') }">
```

> ERROR: But on clicking generated URL is like...
>   https://abc.visual.force.com/apex/%7B!q.Shipment_Number__r.carrier_website__c%7D

I hope my logic is correct and only missing out the syntax. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your formula is wrong.

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!IF(!CONTAINS(q.Shipment_Number__r.carrier_website__c, 'http'), '', 'http://')&q.Shipment_Number__r.carrier_website__c}">
```

You should fix the following mistakes:

1. Starting a formula `{!}` within a formula doesn't work
2. `CONTAINS('http', '')` will return `true` because NOTHING is part of the word "HTTP"